# Index/Match syntax is correct, but lookup cell is not pulling in values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table where I want to lookup values from a sheet based on a data validation list.

Sheet 1: has lookup value in cell `B2`

Array lists exist in `By Rows` worksheet

`=IFERROR(INDEX('By Rows'!B:B,MATCH($B$2,'By Rows'!A:A,0)),"")`

I've done index/match lookups 1000s of times, but not sure what could be triggering the error that results in a blank lookup

Comment: A few things to make sure to do when using an index match, confirm that column B and column A use the same data type (not values as text on one but not the other, for example). Alternatively, make sure B2 has the correct info in the cell as a trailing space or typing error would result in a non-exact match and therefore the blank lookup.

Comment: @MarkS. so that seems to have helped. Is there any reason why my array list column references aren't being auto updated (B:B, C:C, etc) when I drag down the formula? I have the lookup value and lookup value array list locked

Comment: MATCH always returns the FIRST match, if your input is the same the output will always be the same.

Comment: @NidenK, It wouldn't be auto-updated for those columns because as you copy the formula from left to right the reference column is moving with it. You likely need to lock these cells using `F4` (PC users), or surrounding the B:B with $ ($B:$B), but without knowing how you're copying the formula I can't point to the exact issue besides it being related to one of those columns not being locked. I figured you were simply dragging the formula down, not across.

Comment: "what could be triggering the error that results in a blank lookup" ... >> the `IFERROR()` in your function triggers the "" (blank) ... | And the error is due to exact match not found.. | right?